# how to add a custom button to Ckeditor in angular 2 RC1 version

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I can use Ckeditor in Angular 2 RC1 by using this code :

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/X5whPqDhLS6RjTR2N8hT?p=preview
```

But I don't know how to add a custom button to the toolbar . Thanks for help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CKEditor provide an API to do it, just follow this tutorial:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1

To use it directly in Typescript you need to install the CKEditor definitions files using **TSD**:

```
npm i tsd -g
```

Then:

```
tsd install ckeditor --save
```

Don't forget to add the d.ts file in your compilation cycle, usually inside the app entry point:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/ckeditor/ckeditor.d.ts" />
```